# View All Web Analytics in a Single Application?

Tags: analytics

Is there a web service and/or application which will allow me to monitor the measurements from multiple analytics services? I'd like a single place to view the information from [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics), [Yahoo! Web Analytics](http://web.analytics.yahoo.com/), [Mint](http://haveamint.com/), [Quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/), etc.

Comment: +1 great question. I had no idea it was even possible to expose google analytics data outside of the analytics site.

Comment: It is. They have an Analytics Data Export API (http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/). For instance, here is a local (romanian) service that that can be used to publish Google Analytics stats: http://t5.ro/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an iPhone, you could try the [Ego](http://ego-app.com/) app. It covers Google Analytics and Mint and a few other.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the analytics tools has an API you can use to login and pull data.  Just a matter of doing it for each tool and making an interface for yourself.

But on a side-note... trying to track things with multiple tools dooms you to a life of headache, as you will always be wondering and asking why numbers never exactly matchup.